# How to pass variables generated inside controller method to ExceptionHandler

Tags: spring

I am in need of passing a variable generated inside controller method to exception handler.

The variable is logging class in which the information is set by variable service classes.

The following code will explain my intention.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody byte[] handleRequest(HttpServletRequest httpReq){
    CmpLog cmpLog = new CmpLog();
    cmpLog.setClient_ip(getClientIp(httpReq));
    ....
    testService.businessLogic(cmpLog);
    }



@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public @ResponseBody byte[] exceptionHandler(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e){

    // How do I somehow get the cmpLog in the above method?
    cmpLogService.create(cmpLog);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `handleRequest` you can do

`httpReq.setAttribute("cmpLog", cmpLog )` (somewhere before the exception is generated)

and inside `exceptionHandler` you can do

`CmpLog cmpLog = (CmpLog)request.getAttribute("cmpLog")`

Comment: Thank you. I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new exception subclass. Put that value into that and read it in the `exceptionHandler`.

e.g.

```
class MyException extends Exception {
  private Object value;

  MyException(Object value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public Object getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}


@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody byte[] handleRequest(HttpServletRequest httpReq){
    CmpLog cmpLog = new CmpLog();
    cmpLog.setClient_ip(getClientIp(httpReq));
    ....
    testService.businessLogic(cmpLog);

    throw new MyException(someValue);
}



@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public @ResponseBody byte[] exceptionHandler(HttpServletRequest request, MyException e){

    // How do I somehow get the cmpLog in the above method?
    cmpLogService.create(cmpLog + e.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Because the exception can be thrown at different classes, I think setting the instance in the request would be better in my case. I think it is a formal and stable approach, though.